# ¿Cómo puedo asignar un valor select a una variable y que esta no sea undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, array, select

Estoy con un proyecto, simple. Quiero que un select tenga 3 datos 10, 20 y 40. Que por defecto cargue 10 y que con cada selección me actualice una variable que usaré para crear un Array. Concretame, 10, 20 y 40, son el numero de elementos que recogerá de un array más grande (preguntas).

Si lo pico a mano, funciona, si lo pongo así... nada.
Gracias de antemano a quien me de un poco de luz :)

```js
window.onload = function() {
    fillBook();
}

var first_select;

function fillBook(){    
   first_select = document.getElementById('first-select').value;
   console.log(first_select);
}

//db_preguntas
var preguntas = [
    "Q_1", 
    "Q_2", 
    "Q_3",
    //... hay muchas

];
//db_respuestas
var respuestas = [
    ["CORRECTA r1_1", "incorrecta r2_1", "incorrecta r3_1", "incorrecta r4_1"],
    ["CORRECTA r1_2", "incorrecta r2_2", "incorrecta r3_2", "incorrecta r4_2"],
    ["CORRECTA r1_3", "incorrecta r2_3", "incorrecta r3_3", "incorrecta r4_3"],
    //... hay muchas

];

var n_Qs = first_select; //***esta es la variable de la discordia ******//

n_QsTOT = preguntas.length;
    
    const arr_Qs = new Array(preguntas);
    for (let i = 0; i < preguntas.length - 1; i++) {
        arr_Qs[i] = i + 1;
    }
    arr_Qs.sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);
    const newArray_Q = arr_Qs.slice(0, n_Qs); //nuevo Array: newArray_Q

    function logArrayElements(i, index, newArray_Q) {
        console.log("Q["+index+ "] = "+i);
    }
    newArray_Q.forEach(logArrayElements);
```

```html
    <select id="first-select" onchange="fillBook()">
        <option value="10" selected>10 preguntas</option>
        <option value="20">20 preguntas</option>
        <option value="40">40 preguntas</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos :)

Answer (score 0):

Asigna el valor a la variable `n_Qs` dentro de la función `fillBook()`

```
 function fillBook(){    
       first_select = document.getElementById('first-select').value;
       n_Qs = first_select;
    }
```

Adicional a eso, el código que llena el arreglo de preguntas debe ir dentro de una función que también se llame dentro de `fillBook()`

```js
//db_preguntas
var preguntas = [
  "Q_1",
  "Q_2",
  "Q_3",
  //... hay muchas
];
//db_respuestas
var respuestas = [
  ["CORRECTA r1_1", "incorrecta r2_1", "incorrecta r3_1", "incorrecta r4_1"],
  ["CORRECTA r1_2", "incorrecta r2_2", "incorrecta r3_2", "incorrecta r4_2"],
  ["CORRECTA r1_3", "incorrecta r2_3", "incorrecta r3_3", "incorrecta r4_3"],
  //... hay muchas
];

window.onload = function () {
  fillBook();
};

var first_select;
var n_Qs;

function fillBook() {
  first_select = document.getElementById("first-select").value;
  n_Qs = first_select;
  llenar();
}

function llenar() {
  n_QsTOT = preguntas.length;

  const arr_Qs = new Array(preguntas);
  for (let i = 0; i < preguntas.length - 1; i++) {
    arr_Qs[i] = i + 1;
  }
  arr_Qs.sort(() => (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1));
  const newArray_Q = arr_Qs.slice(0, n_Qs); //nuevo Array: newArray_Q

  function logArrayElements(i, index, newArray_Q) {
    console.log("Q[" + index + "] = " + i);
  }
  newArray_Q.forEach(logArrayElements);
}
```